# Programmatically changing a connection made in IB (OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a simple Document based Core Data app (built around the standard Apple tutorials). At the moment I have a button connected to the add: method of a controller (Sheet Controller) that drops down a modal sheet from the main document window. The connection is made in IB (see below from MyDocument.xib). There is also another controller (Another Controller)

[image: IB Connections]

My question is how do I programatically change the buttons action method to point to a method in 'Another Controller' instead of the 'Sheet Controller it is wired up to in IB

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [NSControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `setTarget` and `setAction` methods.

There *is* some special magic associated with making the connections hang together in the first place, but once it's all wired up in the running application a connection is a connection regardless of how it was originally made.

Although -- it's worth considering whether you could allow the [responder chain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2) to take care of things rather than explicitly retargeting the action yourself. That, at least in part, is what it's there for...

Comment: Is the sensible approach to avoid hybrid IB and programmatic bindings. Just use IB to lay separate views out but instantiate the view controllers and attach all bindings to the view manually?

Comment: @AJ opinions differ, but I don't see any problem with doing both. Spurning the convenience of IB for reasons of purism seems pretty self-defeating.